# Calculating the coordinates for the center of a circle in an image

Tags: image, algorithm, matlab

[image]

Say I have this image and I want to get the center of each circle in (X , Y).

Is there an algorithm to do so in MatLab??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a result using cross-correlation with artificial circle as a filter.
The result is [row, column] from upper left corner:

```
>> disp(centers)
         483        1347
         460         662
         478        1001
         451         290
```

There is no detailed comments, please ask it required.

```
im = rgb2gray(im2double(imread('D:/temp/circles.jpg')));
r = 117; % define radius of circles
thres_factor = 0.9; % see usage
%%
[x, y] = meshgrid(-r : r);
f = sqrt(x .^ 2 + y .^ 2) >= r;
%%
im = im - mean(im(:));
im = im / std(im(:));
f = f - mean(f(:));
f = f / std(f(:)) / numel(f);
imf_orig = imfilter(im, f, 'replicate');
%% search local maximas
imf = imf_orig;
[n_idx, m_idx] = meshgrid(1 : size(imf, 2), 1 : size(imf, 1));
threshold = thres_factor * max(imf(:));
centers = []; % this is the result
while true
    if max(imf(:)) < threshold
        break;
    end
    [m, n] = find(imf == max(imf(:)), 1, 'first');
    centers = cat(1, centers, [m, n]);
    % now set this area to NaN to skip it in the next iteration
    idx_nan = sqrt((n_idx - n) .^ 2 + (m_idx - m) .^ 2) <= r;
    imf(idx_nan) = nan;
end
```

[image]

Comment: The guy who used the code said it worked and he asked 
"Where should I put the plot command and which variable is used?"

Comment: this is done by `figure, imagesc(imf_orig); colorbar;`. Obviously, after calculation of `imf_orig`.

Answer (score 5):

That's possible with one call to [regionprops](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/images/ref/regionprops.html):

```
img = imread('KxJEJ.jpg');                      % read the image
imgbw = ~im2bw(img,graythresh(img));            % convert to grayscale

stats  = regionprops(bwlabel(imgbw), 'centroid','area'); % call regionprops to find centroid and area of all connected objects
area = [stats.Area];                            % extract area
centre = cat(1,stats.Centroid);                 % extract centroids

centre = centre(area>10,:);                     % filter out dust specks in the image
```

Now `centre` contains an `Nx2` array: first column is x-position, second column is y-position of the centres:

```
centre =

   289.82       451.73
   661.41       461.21
   1000.8       478.01
   1346.7       482.98
```

Comment: they have encountered this error 
http://www4.0zz0.com/2012/11/13/21/243181924.jpg

Comment: you must be using an older version, what happens if you add what the error suggests: `stats=regionprops(bwlabel(imgbw),'centroid','area');` ?

Answer (score 1):

I recall doing that at the university, **many** years ago!

What we did was to apply a threshold and make everything black and white. Then, we blobbed out the white area (non-circle) so it spread onto the circles.

When they started to disappear, we had the coordinates.

You could also pick two points at the circumference, find the exact middle of the line between them and then draw a perpendicular line through that point. If the middle of the new line **is** the center of the circle.

Comment: can you please tell me more about "blobing " ..
Forgive my ignorance but im not that  good at matlab and im asking this question on behalf of my friend ...
dose it have anything to do with this ??
http://www.commsp.ee.ic.ac.uk/~jahangiri/Blobdetector.html